# Assets + multiple files + file manipulations: offset not working

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, grid

I've got a grid field (slides) that contains 2 Data Types:

1. Text Input - field name: **text**
2. Assets (multiple selections allowed.) - field name: **img**

The Assets folder that has been selected has a image modification called 'sml'.

I can get all the default images outputted in my template in 2 different ways (based on 3 files being added):

Example file names: img_1.png, img_2.png, img_3.png

Example file folder: /content/

1:

```
{slides}
  {slides:img:url offset="0"}, 
  {slides:img:url offset="1"}, 
  {slides:img:url offset="2"}, 
{/slides}
```

2:

```
{slides}
  {slides:img}
    {slides:img:url}, 
  {/slides:img}
{/slides}
```

Both examples above output:

```
/content/img_1.png, 
/content/img_2.png, 
/content/img_3.png,
```

But using the same logic for the image manipulations, example 1 above only shows the first image?

```
{slides}
  {slides:img:url:sml offset="0"}, 
  {slides:img:url:sml offset="1"}, 
  {slides:img:url:sml offset="2"}, 
{/slides}
```

Outputs:

```
    /content/_sml/img_1.png, 
/content/_sml/img_1.png, 
/content/_sml/img_1.png,



{slides}
  {slides:img:}
    {slides:img:url:sml}, 
  {/slides:img}
{/slides}
```

Outputs:

```
/content/_sml/img_1.png, 
/content/_sml/img_2.png, 
/content/_sml/img_3.png,
```